# Running a remote script with parameters using ansible script module

Tags: bash, syntax, ansible

I'm trying to execute a script that takes a single parameter (a filepath+name) on a remote host.

```
- name: Run Script
  hosts: host_alias
  tasks:
     - script: "{{ script_file_path }}/script.sh"
       with_items: 
         - "{{ target_file_path }}/{{ target_file_name }}.conf"
```

Currently, I'm getting a syntax error. Is this the best way to go about doing this, and if so what would the proper syntax be?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for a syntax error here (actually there is no reason for any error if only variables were specified).

---

You defined a loop, but you don't use the iterated data.
At minimum, you need to add a reference to the `item`:

```
- name: Run Script
  hosts: host_alias
  tasks:
    - script: "{{ script_file_path }}/script.sh {{ item }}"
      with_items: 
        - "{{ target_file_path }}/{{ target_file_name }}.conf"
```